# Marginal pseudo-likelihood and consistency?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, marginal-distribution, consistency

For a given set of random variables, $X_1,...,X_n$ we know that in many cases finding the maximum of the pseudo likelihood: $$PL(x_1,\ldots,x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^n p(x_i | x_1,\ldots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)$$ gives a consistent estimator. Is there anything known about "marginal" pseudo-likelihood, i.e. is the global maximum of $$\sum_{x_1} PL(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$ also a consistent estimator under some assumptions?

Comment: What is the index of the summation?